# Custom UITextField, init with no arguments

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a custom `UITextField` and I'm trying to declare it like:

```
let textField = StandardTextField() // pretty much like UITextField()
```

My custom text field looks like:

```
class StandardTextField: UITextField {

    init(frame: CGRect, size: CGFloat) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // some initialization
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

This is giving me an error because `TextField` has no initializer with no arguments. I tried adding:

```
init() {
    super.init()
}
```

But this isn't possible since `super.init()` isn't the designated initializer. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently out of town. I appreciate your help and will try as soon as I'm back home :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for a convenience initialiser. But you will need to define a default frame size for your UITextField. Try like this:

```
class StandardTextField: UITextField {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        // some initialisation for init with no arguments
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //  some initialisation for init with frame
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to. I'm using autolayout. How do I ignore the stupid frame and have autolayout figure out the frame for me?  I don't want to set the frame.

Comment: You need a frame to start. It can be any size

Answer (score 0):

Well unless I'm blatantly missing something, you've declared your class as `class Textfield: UITextField` and based on how you're trying to create your object, your class should be defined as `class StandardField: UITextField` and the class doesn't need any initializers as Leo said.

```
class StandardTextField: UITextField {
    //no initializers
}
```

Comment: Sorry, while making this question I changed the name. I've fixed it in the question.

Comment: @Laap all you need to do is to remove init and required init

Comment: Yep I was just testing in playground. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @LeoDabus How should I do the custom initialization later on then though? Like setting the font and backgroundcolor etc. (Which is the point of me creating this custom text field, so I don't have to repeat it every time)

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the tip. I tried overriding it but it's giving me an error about the getter from superclass UIView.

Comment: You can also override frame initialiser or maybe a convenience initialiser

Comment: @Laap take a look at my post